# Intel uhd 620 reports graphics memory as 4 GB, is this legit?

Tags: memory, drivers, graphics-card

I installed the latest Intel uhd 620 driver and I started the control panel and headed over to the driver section and it reports the graphics memory as `4054 MB`. Why is it showing this when other software from third parties says the uhd has a vram of `128Mbs`? Is there something like `minimum` and `maximum` graphics memory?, enlighten me please.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intel UHD graphics solutions use your CPU RAM. This is known as "shared" graphics memory.

The figure you are seeing is for the maximum amount of shared memory that the GPU will have access too, not that it has its own private memory.

Open the Windows Task Manager, go to the "performance" tab and click the GPU graph on the left hand side and you should see what memory your GPU is using.

[image]

The Intel GPU will likely show "0" for dedicated RAM as the integrated graphics chips do not have their own private RAM.

The "shared" memory will tell you how much of the 4GB is in use.

Comment: Okay thanks, I was just starting to wonder when I play a game like Far Cry 3 on this system where it was gonna get the memory to draw high quality images and graphics.

Comment: To clarify a final point, the 128MB reported by tools is likely the permanently allocated shared memory, it is the minimum needed by the GPU to actually work. It might be reported as "dedicated" but it is still your system RAM. The rest of the memory is allocated by games and programs as needed.

Comment: mine shows 4 GB for both(`Shared GPU Memory and GPU memory`) on the task manager panel. The output is on this link https://imgur.com/a/8cAsaO8, is that weird?

Comment: @David yes, that is right then,  you have only shared memory. I just misremembered how it was allocated.